# How to test a swift generic type another one?

Tags: swift, generics

I have some generic type class but no instance of object to test. What I would like to do is to alter the behavior of the function according to the runtime type.

```
class MyGenericUtility<SomeGenericClass> {

    func myFunction() {
        // so far I have tested "is", "==" and "==="
        if SomeGenericClass is SomeRealClass {
            println("some special stuff there")
        }
        println("some generic stuff as the name tells")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the class type, using SomeGenericClass.self == SomeRealClass.self as,

```
class MyGenericUtility<SomeGenericClass> {
    func myFunction() {
        if SomeGenericClass.self == SomeRealClass.self {
            print("SomeRealClass stuffs")
        } else if SomeGenericClass.self == String.self {
            print("String stuffs")
        }
    } 
}


let someRealUtility = MyGenericUtility<SomeRealClass>()
someRealUtility.myFunction()

let stringUtility = MyGenericUtility<String>()
stringUtility.myFunction()
```

Comment: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type SomeRealClass.type and ...`

Comment: Are you using latest version of Swift. It should be possible with latest swift.

Comment: Swift 1.2 I guess. Swift 2 is still in beta isn't it? I don't pick any Swift version when creating a playground and I am running XCode 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing at runtime, you should generally handle this at compile time with constrained extensions (this assumes Swift 2). Doing it this way avoids any need to do unsafe `as!` casting when you need to access type-specific parts of the instance.

```
class MyGenericUtility<SomeGenericClass> {
}

// Special handling for `SomeRealClass`
extension MyGenericUtility where SomeGenericClass: SomeRealClass {
    func myFunction() {
        print("SomeRealClass stuffs")
    }
}

// Default handling for any unspecified class
extension MyGenericUtility {
    func myFunction() {
        print("Other stuffs")
    }
}

let someRealUtility = MyGenericUtility<SomeRealClass>()
someRealUtility.myFunction()

let stringUtility = MyGenericUtility<String>()
stringUtility.myFunction()
```

Note that this is based on inheritance, not equality, so any subclass of `SomeRealClass` would get the `SomeRealClass` behavior.

Comment: This is Swift 2 only, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. It requires Swift 2.

Comment: Ok, nice use of those extension features though. I had forgot them from the WWDC talks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the generic type directly, you need to use a property of that type when comparing with "is".

```
class MyGenericUtility<T> {
    var a: T

    func myFunction() {
        if a is Int {
            println("some special stuff there")
        }
        println("some generic stuff as the name tells")
    }

    init(value: T) {
        a = value
    }
}

let test = MyGenericUtility(value: 5)
test.myFunction()  
// Output: some special stuff there
//         some generic stuff as the name tells

let test2 = MyGenericUtility(value: "foo")
test2.myFunction()
// Output: some generic stuff as the name tells
```